# Using requireJs and Qtip

Tags: requirejs

This is my main.aspx

> ```
> <%--RequireJS--%>
> <script data-main="coopjs/app" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.js"></script>
> ```

This is in my app.js

```
requirejs.config({
    "app_name": "coop",
    "baseUrl": "coopjs",
    "paths": {
        "jquery_ui" : "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui",   
        "jquery": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery",
        "coopDragDrop": "../Scripts/coop/coopDragDrop",
        "qTip2 ": "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"
    }
});
```

This is again in my main.aspx

```
(function () {
            require(["qTip2"], function () {
                alert('hi');
            });
        })();
```

It tries to load locally instead of the CDN, throwing the error

```
GET http://localhost:43122/coopjs/qTip2.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space in your `paths` setup for qTip:

```
"qTip2 ": "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"
```

Change `"qTip2 "` to `"qTip2"`. You could even remove the quotes. When do you `require` you use `"qTip2"` which does not match `"qTip2 "`.

There is another problem. RequireJS loads the file pointed to by `data-main` asynchronously so there is no guarantee that your `requirejs.config` call will happen before you require qTip2. So move this piece of code into your `coopjs/app.js` file, after your `requirejs.config` call:

```
require(["qTip2"], function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: I remove the space and quotes but same problem persists.

Comment: There's another problem I did not see earlier because I was concentrating on the most evident problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry I have really no clue what is going on. Am I suppose to expect an alert box when I run my page?

Comment: Did you make the change I suggested? If yes, are you still getting a 404? If you use `console.log` instead of `alert` do you see `hi` on the console?